# AngularJS - overriding ngInclude directive not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I am trying to add cache busting for ng-include partials as below:

```
app.directive('ngInclude', ['$http', '$q', '$rootScope', '$timeout',
    function ($http, $q, $rootScope, $timeout) {
        return{
            restrict : "EAC",
            scope : {
                src : '@'
            },
            priority : 1000,
            link : function($scope, elem, $attrs, model) {
                console.log($scope.src);
                $scope.src = $scope.src.replace('.html', '.html?v=' + pageConfig.rv);
                $attrs.src = $scope.src;
                console.log($scope.src);
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

I gave priority of 1000 to override the default 400 of ngInclude. I can see the `src` changed in console but http call does not include my `v` param. I believe my ngInclude is called after actual one is rendered.

Is there any way to override the ngInclude behavior or other way to achieve cache busting?

Comment: Assuming your templates never end up in the template cache, why not just add a general HTTP request interceptor? Also, you'd probably have better luck decorating the existing `ngInclude` than attempting to build your own but I would definitely try an HTTP interceptor first.

Comment: I thought overriding ngInclude will be cleaner, because in future its easy to find and modify for specific needs. I will try out http interceptor also. I tried decorator as well, which didn't work.